# djano-registration not authenticating users on login

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I'm using a (compatible) Custom User model. The registering part of django-registration is working perfectly. However, when I take the user to the log-in page from a navbar, The user is never really authenticated. If I put in a wrong password it will correctly through and error, but when username and password are correct, the user is simply redirected to the correct page, just without getting authenticated.

My `register/urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
   # a custom RegistrationForm that works perfectly
    url(r'^register/$',
        RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=GeneralUserForm),
        name='registration_register'),
    url(r'^', include('registration.backends.hmac.urls')),
]
```

My `register/templates/registration/login.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post" action=".">
  {% csrf_token %} 
  {{ form.as_p }}

  <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Log in' %}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>

<p>{% trans "Forgot password" %}? <a href="{% url 'auth_password_reset' %}">{% trans "Reset it" %}</a>!</p>
<p>{% trans "Not member" %}? <a href="{% url 'registration_register' %}">{% trans "Register" %}</a>!</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Relevant snippets from `settings.py`:

```
# Setting custom User Model
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'register.GeneralUser'

# for guardian to work

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', # this is default
    'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend',
)

# Setting limit on days
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: can you post your view code?

Comment: I don't have a login view. Isn't the whole point of Django-registration is that it's supposed to handle that automatically? (by subclassing the login form?)

Comment: what is the error that you are getting? can you describe that and post the form rather that you are using

Comment: So as explained in the OP, when the username and password are correct, there is no error at all, but the user isn't authenticated (I'm checking that in the template of the target redirection URL with `if user.authenticated`.

Comment: Regarding the form: again they are supplied by Django-registration and you can see the login.html in the OP.

Comment: url(r'^/', include('registration.backends.hmac.urls')),

just try to change the url line and check once

Comment: The login URL stops working when I do that. Django also throws a warning that the forward slash is redundant and should be removed.

Comment: add a $ after that

Comment: Still, with `url(r'^/$', include('registration.backends.hmac.urls'))`, `/accounts/login/` returns and error: `The current URL, accounts/login/, didn't match any of these.`

Comment: url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.hmac.urls'))

Comment: I don't think that's going to work. I'm already referring to the accounts URL in the root urls.py, [like so](https://pastebin.com/yBcT6a50).

Comment: thats why you are running to the problem. change them and follow django-registration docu as you told and do you have django.contrib.auth in your installed apps in settings file

Comment: ? I'm not doing anything fundamentally different than what is specified in the docs. Also: Just tried what you suggested and it didn't work, so it's not the problem.

Comment: django.contrib.auth in your installed apps in settings file

Comment: But it's already there.

Comment: sorry made a mistake the url will be url(r^$)

Comment: So is this with my original setup, or your suggestion to remove the redirections from root URL to accounts/urls.py?

Comment: no keep all, just add a $ where you are including it

Comment: It's simply giving an error. `$` means end of string so it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Occam's Razor, always.

My problem was much simpler:

```
{% if user.authenticated %} # should simply be user.is_authenticated
    <li>Welcome {{ user.username }}</li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
{% else %}
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/accounts/register">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="/accounts/login">Login</a></li>
    <li>Welcome {{ user.date_joined }}</li>
{% endif %}
```